# CentOS 6.5 + KVM (Virtual Machine Manager) create shortcut - Laucher for Guest Machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, virtualization, centos

How can I create a Launcher on my desktop for guests machines inside of KVM on desktop of CentOS 6.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `virt-manager` which brings up a GUI for launching/interacting with your guest KVM guests or you could create a shell script to do what you want and then setup a shortcut to the script on your desktop.

#### virt-manager

[image: ss #1]

#### desktop icon

First create a script like so, saving it to perhaps `$HOME/bin/kvm_someguest.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# assuming it's started but you could do this oto
# virsh start someguest

virt-viewer someguest
```

Make sure it's executable.

```
$ chmod +x $HOME/bin/kvm_someguest.bash
```

Now make a shortcut on the desktop to it. For this create a `.desktop` file like so:

```
$ more ~/Desktop/kvm_someguest.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=$HOME/bin/kvm_someguest.bash
Terminal=false
Name=KVM Someguest
GenericName=KVM Someguest
```

Now when you double click it it should run your KVM instance.

Comment: @user3134198 - glad that resolved your Q. You can also upvote in addition to accepting 8-).